# What's a more efficient way to write this code?

Tags: c++, inheritance

So, I'm a newbie in C++ and I'm trying to learn about inheritance. I wrote out a program that just simply prints out the perimeter of different shapes, namely a square and a triangle. Unfortunately, the way I'm doing it ends up with some duplicated code. Here's what I mean:

```
#include <iostream>

class Shape {
public:
  int sides;
  int sideLength;
};

class Square : public Shape {
public:
  int sides = 4;
  int sideLength = 6;
  void calculatePerimeter() {
    int perimeter = sideLength * sides;
    std::cout << "perimeter length: " << perimeter << std::endl;
  }
};

class Triangle : public Shape {
public:
  int sides = 3;
  int sideLength = 4;
  void calculatePerimeter() {
    int perimeter = sideLength * sides;
    std::cout << "perimeter length: " << perimeter << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  Square s;
  std::cout << "number of sides a square has: " << s.sides << std::endl;

  Triangle t;
  std::cout << "number of sides a triangle has: " << t.sides << std::endl;

  s.calculatePerimeter();
  t.calculatePerimeter();
}
```

As you can see, the `calculatePerimeter` function is being used in the Square and the Triangle classes. Putting it in the Shape class and calling it resulted in an output of 0. How can I make this more efficient so I don't have to copy/paste it for every shape class I make?

Comment: Note that `Square` has actually 4 members: `Shape::sides`, `Shape::sideLength`, `Square::sides`, `Square::sideLength`...

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed it does, I come from Java where declaring a variable in an extended class overrides the variable instead of duplicating it...Looks like I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use inheritance, you factor common behavior and state in the base class and make derived classes extend this state and behavior with their specific functionality.

1. Remove the sides and sideLength members from Shape. Instead, provide virtual functions in class Shape that return those values, and have the derived classes override them.
2. Move method calculate perimeter to class Shape, and implement it using the getSides() and getSideLength()

   ```
   #include <iostream>

   class Shape {
   public:
     virtual int getSides() = 0;
     virtual int getSideLength() = 0;
     void calculatePerimeter() {
       int perimeter = getSideLength() * getSides();
       std::cout << "perimeter length: " << perimeter << std::endl;
     }
   };

   class Square : public Shape {
   public:
     virtual int getSides() {
       return 4;
     }

     virtual int getSideLength() {
       return 6;
     }
   };

   class Triangle : public Shape {
   public:
     virtual int getSides() {
       return 3;
     }

     virtual int getSideLength() {
       return 4;
     }
   };
   ```

This is what is known as a Template Method design pattern (not to be confused with the template function concept of C++, which is an entirely unrelated concept specific to this language).

Comment: Thank you so much, it works great and is far less ugly. Thanks for explaining the answer as well, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You need a constructor for `Shape` and to pass the variables through from the derived constructors. Then you can move `calculatePerimiter` into the parent class.

```
class Shape {
public:
  Shape(int n_sides, int side_length) : sides(n_sides), sideLength(side_length) {}

  void calculatePerimeter() {
    int perimeter = sideLength * sides;
    std::cout << "perimeter length: " << perimeter << std::endl;
  }

  int sides;
  int sideLength;
};

class Square : public Shape {
public:
  Square() : Shape(4,6) {}     
};

class Triangle : public Shape {
public:
  Triangle() : Shape(3, 4) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

`int sides = 3;
int sideLength = 4;`

is creating new variables with a local scope view. Without running your code, I would imagine if you simply got rid of the 'int' in front of both lines should fix your problem.

Edit: put them into a constructor of course.

Edit: Ok, combining code...

```
    class Triangle : public Shape {
public:

  Triangle ()
  {
    sides = 3;
    sideLength = 4;
  }

  void calculatePerimeter() {
    int perimeter = sideLength * sides;
    std::cout << "perimeter length: " << perimeter << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Depending what it is you are trying to understand, the other answers are better solutions to the problem. This is simple enough to just put parameters into the calcualatePerimeter() method, but that of course does not test your understanding of variables within a scope, which seemed to be your stumbling block.

Comment: If `int` is removed then a compile-time error would occur. How does that solve the above problem?

Comment: Write a constructor for each overridden class and move the variables into it.

Comment: class Triangle : public Shape {
public:

 Triangle ()
 {
   sides = 3;
   sideLength = 4;
 };
 
  void calculatePerimeter() {
    int perimeter = sideLength * sides;
    std::cout << "perimeter length: " << perimeter << std::endl;
  }
};

Comment: you should combine this with your answer to make it a complete one.

Answer (score 0):

You can acess immediate base class members and also initialise them.

```
class Shape {
public:
  int sides;
  int sideLength;
  Shape(int m,int n)
  {
      sides =m;
     sideLength = n;
  }
};

class Square : public Shape {
public:
  Square(int j,int k);

  int calculatePerimeter() {
    int perimeter = sides * sideLength ;
    std::cout << "perimeter length: " << perimeter << std::endl;
    return perimeter;
  }
};

Square::Square(int j,int k):Shape(j,k)
{


}
```

Comment: But square always has 4 sides so that shouldn't be a variable given from outside.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach for a compiler that supports C++11...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class Seq>
void purge(Seq& s) {
    for (auto x: s) {
        delete x;
        x = nullptr;
    }
}

class Shape {
public: 
    virtual void calculatePerimeter() = 0; // to avoid object slicing
    virtual ~Shape() {};
};

class Square : public Shape {
    int m_sides{0};
    int m_sideLength{0};
public: 
    Square() = delete; // suppress default constructor
    Square(int sides, int sideLength): m_sides(sides), m_sideLength(sideLength) {}
    ~Square() {}
    void calculatePerimeter() {
        int perimeter = m_sideLength * m_sides;
        cout << "Square perimeter length: " << perimeter << endl;
    }
};

class Triangle : public Shape {
    int m_sides{0};
    int m_sideLength{0};
public: 
    Triangle() = delete; // suppress default constructor
    Triangle(int sides, int sideLength): m_sides(sides), m_sideLength(sideLength) {}
    ~Triangle() {}
    void calculatePerimeter() {
        int perimeter = m_sideLength * m_sides;
        cout << "Triangle perimeter length: " << perimeter << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    vector<Shape*> vec;

    vec.push_back(new Square(4, 7));
    vec.push_back(new Triangle(3, 13));

    for (auto x: vec) {
        x->calculatePerimeter();
    }

    // clean up
    purge(vec);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So we can create `Square` or `Triangle` with 42 sides :-)

Answer (score 0):

The template way:

```
template <std::size_t SideCount, typename T>
class EquilateralPolygon
{
public:
    explicit EquilateralPolygon(T sideLength) : sideLength(sideLength) {}
    std::size_t GetSideCount() const { return SideCount; }
    T GetSideLength() const { return sideLength; }

    T calculatePerimeter() const { return SideCount * sideLength; }
private:
    T sideLength;
};

template <std::size_t SideCount, typename T>
void displayPerimeter(const EquilateralPolygon<SideCount, T>& p) {
    std::cout << "perimeter length: " << p.calculatePerimeter() << std::endl;
}

using EquilateralTriangle = EquilateralPolygon<3, std::size_t>;
using Square = EquilateralPolygon<4, std::size_t>;
```

And usage:

```
int main() {
    Square s(5);
    std::cout << "number of sides a square has: " << s.GetSideCount() << std::endl;

    EquilateralTrianglet(5);
    std::cout << "number of sides a triangle has: " << t.GetSideCount() << std::endl;

    displayPerimeter(s);
    displayPerimeter(t);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/w2UnA4)

Answer (score -1):

This should answer your question. Also, I would recommend passing the values of `sides` and `sideLength` as parameters to the function calls to enable generic usage.

```
#include <iostream>

class Shape {
    protected void calculatePerimeter(int sides, int sideLength) {
    int perimeter = sideLength * sides;
    std::cout << "perimeter length: " << perimeter << std::endl;
  }
};

class Square : public Shape {
  int sides = 4;
  int sideLength = 6;
  public void calculatePerimeter()
  {
      Shape::calculatePerimeter(sides, sideLength);
  }
};

class Triangle : public Shape {
  int sides = 3;
  int sideLength = 4;
  public void calculatePerimeter()
  {
      Shape::calculatePerimeter(sides, sideLength);
  }
};

int main() {
  Square s;
  std::cout << "number of sides a square has: " << s.sides << std::endl;

  Triangle t;
  std::cout << "number of sides a triangle has: " << t.sides << std::endl;

  s.calculatePerimeter();
  t.calculatePerimeter();
}
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer, especially if the code doesn't answer the question. He asked for ways to reduce copy/pasting code, but your answer still requires it when there's a very simple way to not.

Comment: @JohnDrouhard Its a different way of approaching the problem, yes my code repeats the function definition but at least not the content inside it. Moreover, I wanted to indicate here an alternative way of calling the base class methods. As you can see, the user is a 'newbie' and I don't see how you can throw answers containing 'virtual' and 'templates' (without proper explanation) and expect the user to understand? You talked about a simple solution. I believe my code here is the simplest of all approaches posted above. Do tell me which solution according to you is the simplest for a 'newbie'.